# How to remove added (not installed) dkms

Tags: drivers, kernel, dkms

For some reason I installed a driver long time ago and it is no longer in use, and in root permission I checked the `dkms status` it shows this:
[image]

I tried to removed it by using the following commands (separately)

```
 dkms uninstall -k rtl88x2bu -v 5.2.4.4
 dkms uninstall -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.2.4.4
 dkms remove -k rtl88x2bu -v 5.2.4.4
 dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.2.4.4
```

So I wonder how to remove the added driver.

Comment: Since the 5.2.4.4 version is not installed, you should be able to just remove the files from /usr/src.

Comment: I removed it, but when I checked the 'dkms status' it's still there.

Comment: See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dkms.8.html . I believe the command to remove that module would be `dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.2.4.4 --all`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dkms.8.html

In the link it is stated:

> ```
>    remove [module/module-version] [-k kernel/arch] [--all]
>
>        Removes  a module/version or module/version/kernel/arch combination from the tree.  If
>        the module is currently installed, it first uninstalls  it  and  if  applicable,  will
>        replace  it  with  its  original_module.   Use the --all option in order to remove all
>        instances for every kernel at once.
> ```

Since the module you want to remove doesn't have a kernel associated with it the command to remove it would be:

```
dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.2.4.4 --all
```

Where you only need to specify the `module/version` then `--all` to remove module completely from the system.